# Python, Tkinter; How to use grid_forget() when deselecting a check box?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I have a script I am working on and I am having a problem trying to get a frame to hide when a check box is deselected. The script I am working on uses a check button to call a command to show a frame containing some text entry fields. The problem is when I deselect the check box the frame does not disappear. Here are the pieces of the script:

```
    self.name3 = Name3(self)
    self.check_var4 = tk.IntVar()

    tk.Checkbutton(self,
                   text="Search", variable=self.check_var4,
                   onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, width=10,
                   command=self.show_name3
                   ).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E', ipadx=20)
```

which calls:

```
    def show_name3(self):
        '''Shows Search Widget'''
        self.name3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E',
                         padx=15, pady=5, ipadx=15, ipady=5)
```

which in turn calls:

```
    class Name3(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):

            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            tk.Label(self,
                    text="info:"
                    ).grid(row=1, sticky='E')
            E3 = Entry(self, bd =2)
            E3.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15)
            tk.Label(self,
                    text="Stuff:"
                    ).grid(row=2, sticky='E')
            E4 = Entry(self, bd =2)
            E4.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=15)
```

I think all I need to do is add a command to use grid.forget() but how? Do I use a "if this then grid.forget" and if so, could someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
def show_name3():
    if self.check_var4.get() == 1:
        self.name3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='E', padx=15, pady=5, ipadx=15, ipady=5)
    else:
        self.name3.grid_forget()
```

It will get the value of `check_var`, which indicates if the `Checkbutton` is on or off. If it is on, it will place `name3` with the grid manager. If it is off, it will remove `name3` from the grid manager.

Comment: I just tried it and I am getting an error that says: global name 'check_var' is not defined. I tried with 'check_var4' and I get the same error.

Comment: Then it's a scope issue. Where is `check_var4` defined in relation to `show_name3`?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's `self.check_var4.get()` if they're all within the same class. My bad.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much this fixed the problem perfectly! I've been trying to figure this out all day.